# Can you update the local origin of an object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I was wondering if there is a way to reset the origin of an STL file after I have either moved or rotated it. So say my object rotation is set originally to (0,0,0), I then rotate it to (20,70,90) degrees. Is there a way that I could update the local origin so that when I call object.position, I get (0,0,0) while the object keeps the rotation I had previously assigned to it rotation?

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.applyMatrix4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Mesh is a scene graph node and applies a chain of transformations to geometry. Geometry classes have methods to transform the vertices - translate, rotate and scale, or with a single Matrix4.

You can for example compute the bounding sphere of the geometry and then translate it by the negative value of the spheres center to center the geometry.